# Need help with a DMP3028LSD-13 - PMOS in dual way power path design. Currently, load resistors are needed to turn the path off

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, powermosfet

I have implemented a bi-directional independent power path using a  DMP3028LSD-13 PMOS. When a supply is connected on the A side (power source +5V,) voltage is reflected on the side B (no device/load) even when the NMOS gate is not triggered, vice versa when a supply is connected on the side B (power source +5V,) voltage is reflected on side A (no device/load.)

We have observed that to fully turn off PMOS we have to provide a <=1 kΩ dummy load resistor on the other end as shown as R9. Even after providing the dummy load, the PMOS turns off partially - 0.29 V is observed and drawing some current. This causes a permanent load which is not good for my battery operated design. I need help to turn off this PMOS properly.

Please suggest how can I fully turn off and turn on this PMOS properly for bi-directional operation.

I have attached the current schematic below for reference.

[image: Schematic diagram]